# Why does the span inside my paragraph have a larger rendered font-size than specified?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a simple paragraph with a span inside it. I have a font-size in `em`'s declared on the paragraph – as well as the span. The issue is, the font-size of the span is not accurate to the `em` I give it. I've noticed this by removing the font-size of the parenting paragraph element, but leaving the span's font-size the same – which for some reason, shrinks the span.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1wfhjpvr/

Now, I know there's something about inheritance happening here – but how can I easily use span font-size declarations, along with my standard font-size declarations on the paragraph element, and get the result I expect?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using a unit which value is relative to the container element. If you wish to 'see' the same value, you should use relative-ems instead.
In your example:

```
<p style="font-size: 1.4em;">
    Test
    <span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
        Test
    </span>
</p>

<p>
    Test
    <span style="font-size: 1.4em;">
        Test
    </span>
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7bo2kLt/

Answer (score 0):

Em is a relative size of the parent container of you have an em with in an em you have a relative size to a relative size. Do you need the em on the span?

Answer (score 0):

Units you are using `em` are relative to parent element, when you want the same value you can use `1em`, so in you example:

```
<span style="font-size: 1em;">
```

There are new units called `rem` (root em), that are relative to body settings. You can use them, they are easier to maintain in cases like this.

[REM browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)

[Nice article about font-sizing](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

So your example could be:

```
<p style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
    Test
    <span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
        Test
    </span>
</p>

<p>
    Test
    <span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
        Test
    </span>
</p>
```

and it will work for you, see updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wfhjpvr/1/)